# Playing Video in C# Applications

Tags: c#, wpf, html, video, awesomium

I have a number of `Buttons` in my C# (`WPF`) application that I would like to play videos. I have tried a number of things so far.

The in-built `MediaElement` successfuly played the videos, however there was a big delay before the video would play ([previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36477688/mediaelement-takes-time-to-play-video-if-its-first-element-loaded)). I never found a solution to this, and as a result I moved on.

I tried another solution which was to use the `WebBrowser` and embed some HTML in it to play a video. This doesn't work because the `WebBrowser` uses an older version of IE which doesn't support HTML5 videos. As a result I moved on to try Awesomium.

This is my code so far for Awesomium;

```
<Grid>
    <osm:WebControl x:Name="webControl" Margin="10"/>
</Grid>
```

In my code behind;

```
private void OnPageLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var videoURI = new Uri(Properties.Settings.Default.FirstVideoPath);
        webControl.LoadHTML(@"<video width = ""100%"" height = ""100%"" controls >
                                <source src = ""C:\Desktop\example.mp4"" type = ""video/mp4"">
                                </video>");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

The HTML works fine when opened up in Chrome, however results in this in my C# application;

[image]

Essentially my question is this. has anyone had any success playing videos in their application NOT using the in-built `MediaElement`? What could I use to achieve what I want to?

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same performance issue with `MediaElement`. To solve it we change from using `MediaElement` to `MediaUriElement`. The `MediaUriElement` is part of the [WPFMediaKit](https://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/releases/view/21215). Note that you might also need to download and install the [Windows Media Codec](https://www.mediaplayercodecpack.com/).

The WPFMediaKit should be downloaded, then retrieve the WPFMediaKit.dll file from the .zip and reference it from you project. Then in XAML you should add this reference:

```
xmlns:mk="clr-namespace:WPFMediaKit.DirectShow.Controls;assembly=WPFMediaKit"
```

And then use the `MediaUriElement` like this:

```
<mk:MediaUriElement Source="Your video path"/>
```